# Prevent Smart Quotes on HTML5 Input

Tags: javascript, html

Had an annoying issue with my web application more recently. Using HTML5, a user can create an account with a login ID. The ID can contain pretty much any character. A user will enter an account ID, for example

Bob'sAccount

And their device (unknown to them) turns the ' into a "smartquote" with the ` style apostrophe

So now their account is created (with a smartquote in the user ID). However, if they try to log in using a device which doesn't automatically create smart quotes, they try to log in using the standard apostrophe, and since it's a different character, their account is not found.

I'm sure I could limit the characters a user can enter for an account ID, but I would rather just prevent the smartquotes from happening in the first place.

Is there a way to disable "smartquotes" in an HTML5 input field?

Comment: `str.replace(/[“”«»„“»«]/g,'"')` will work for double quotes. For single quotes, find the "smart" quote characters and do `str.replace(/smartquoteChars/g,"'")`.

Comment: There is no way to distinguish between people whose software is doing this as they desire and people whose software is doing it against their will.

The solution to 'smart' quotes is for them to not be used, at the very least not outside word processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know what the character is turning into, just replace it with a regular quote before you submit the form.

```
str
            .replace(/[\u2014]/g, "--")        // emdash
            .replace(/[\u2022]/g, "*")         // bullet
            .replace(/[\u2018\u2019]/g, "'")   // smart single quotes
            .replace(/[\u201C\u201D]/g, '"');  // smart double quotes
```

This is just an example, i know it's tedious but that's one way to do it. Check out: https://asna.com/us/tech/kb/doc/remove-smart-quote for a script that has a lot of other special characters that are replaced to serve your same function

Comment: I think this solution is better applied with Regex.

Comment: Yeah the link I provided uses regex in its replace statements, I should just copy that over

Comment: I was afraid it was a more brute force process like this. I may just limit the characters which are allowed for a user ID to numbers and letters.